# Android studio gives me an error cannot resolve symbol maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am following a android development tutorial on online were I am building an app that is similar to uber. A ll of my issue references related to google play kee giving me a "connot resolve symbol maps" error when I hover overt them. I am using firebase version 3.2.1 and I am using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'[Picture of the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsOPe.png)

My build gradle seems to be ok
[picture of my gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3DqE.png)

I have tried restarting android, cleaning and building but nothing works

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Add the maps dependency

```
implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

Comment: I no longer get red marks on my google references but i get this error "AAPT2 error: check logs for details" Im aslo still getting          *"error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/colorError not found., sources=[C:\Users\rverma\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar\c092de2b34e475b6e816c16241fe0ce0\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT"*

Comment: the issue that im getting now is in with that in this line of code  setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map); the "activity_code_map" shows up in red. .I tried to email you my ode in a zip file but the google and outlook email software are prohibiting me from doing that.

Comment: Then you should upload the project on google drive and send me the link.

Comment: i shared it with you on google drive now. You should now have access to it. Also, thank you !